# Issue with Navigation menu looking smaller on other screens

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

so on my screen the navigation bar stretches to almost the end of my screen while on a bigger screen it doesn't reach to the intended limit I'm a beginner at creating websites so i'd like to ask for help in what is the issue here.. i tried using percentage on width but when i make the screen smaller the content get all jumbled which i don't want i want a non responsive menu like that of ebay i guess.

```css
.search [type=text]{
    width: 30em;
 position:absolute;
         top:6%;
         left:15%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    
 
}
.Navigation{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:1em;
 width:80.9em;
 position:fixed;
 top:6em;
 left:2em;
    list-style-type: none;
 padding:0%;
 border-bottom: 1px  solid grey;
 border-top: 1px  solid grey;
    
}

.Navigation a {
    float: left;
 
}

.Navigation li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #484849;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.7em 4.93em;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

.Navigation a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px  solid red;

}
/* class="active" */
.active {
 border-top: 1px  solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px  solid red;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 <style type="text/css">
 .logo{
  position:absolute;
     top:1em;
     left:3em;
 }
 
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<a class="logo" href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo Icon" height="80"></a>
</body>


<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="Navigation">
  <li><a href="Mobiles.php">Mobiles</a></li>
  <li><a href="Vehicles.php">Vehicles</a></li>
  <li><a href="Games.php">Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="Clothes.php">Clothes</a></li>
  <li><a href="Accessories.php">Accessories</a></li>
  <li><a href="Other.php">Other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<form class="search">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set the width of the navbar to be `width:80.9em`;

em is a unit of measurement which is 'the width of 1 M character'
So basically you're setting the width to be 80.9 M's wide.
If you want it to be a percentage, you should use `width: 80%`
which will make the navebat take 80% of the parent's div width.

edit-
Noticed that you mentioned using percetage makes it jumbled in smaller displays.
You can use min-width to make sure your minimum width is enough for your text.
You can also use @media  queries which lets you set how the page will look at different display sizes.
You can read more on it here- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: but doesn't that mean I'm creating a responsive menu? which i don't want ebay for instance lets you resize the browser and the menu doesn't change at all the content cut off.

Comment: using percentage will change the width, yes.  for what you're describing I would use the @media queries, they answers your needs exactly :)